# Telerik RadAutoCompleteBox dropdown is transparent

Tags: c#, telerik

I am using Telerik RadAutoComplete box and whenever I search any value the dropdown that is shown is transparent. I am able to see the background form along with name of the searched values, which is wrong. Below is the client side code

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="txtInstitutionName" runat="server" EmptyMessage="Select School"
     DropDownWidth="200px" AllowCustomEntry="true" TextSettings-SelectionMode="Single" InputType="Text"
     Filter="Contains" Delimiter=" ">                                        
</telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
```

Below is the picture of the faulty RadAutoCompleteBox.

[image]

Kindly Suggest.

Comment: I cannot replicate this issue. Do you have a class that set background color to transparent anywhere? May be a conflict there.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Telerik version 2017.1

This style is a workaround:

```
            <telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox.DropDownItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="0" Background="White" Margin="-2, -2.2">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Subject}" Padding="3"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox.DropDownItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the background color of the PopUp Grid to White.

```
<Grid x:Name="PopupRoot" Background="White">
```

The complete style:

```
<Style x:Key="RadAutoCompleteBoxControlWithBackground" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverVisual"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                    <Border x:Name="MouseOverVisual" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="1" Opacity="0"/>
                    <Border x:Name="FocusVisual" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0">
                        <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" BorderBrush="#FF9BB0CD" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="#FFE2F0FD" CornerRadius="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ScrollViewer" BorderThickness="0" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <telerik:AutoCompleteBoxesItemsControl x:Name="PART_Boxes" BoxesItemTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding BoxesItemTemplateSelector}" BoxesItemStyleSelector="{TemplateBinding BoxesItemStyleSelector}" BoxesItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding BoxesItemTemplate}" BoxesItemStyle="{TemplateBinding BoxesItemStyle}" DisplayMemberPath="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <telerik:AutoCompleteBoxesItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <telerik:AutoCompleteBoxesWrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </telerik:AutoCompleteBoxesItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </telerik:AutoCompleteBoxesItemsControl>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup">
                        <Grid x:Name="PopupRoot" Background="White">
                            <telerik:RadListBox x:Name="PART_ListBox" IsTabStop="False" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding FilteredItems}" ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding DropDownItemTemplate}" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinDropDownWidth}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" SelectedValueBinding="{x:Null}" TextBinding="{x:Null}">
                            </telerik:RadListBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```